# Can I use CodeStar's deployment infrastructure with an existing CodeCommit repo?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, aws-codestar

CodeStar seems to consist of two parts

1. a way to easily generate several related resources and a CodeCommit repo for managing a project and
2. a mechanism for automatically deploying CodeCommit code to run on specific AWS services.

Is there a way to do just (2) with an existing CodeCommit repo? That is can I "hook up" such a repo with some services so that when I push to the repo, the update is pushed to the services?

For example, for an existing Lambda project I currently have a repo that I understand how to easily add to CodeCommit; but for now I update the running Lambda service manually with something like `aws lambda  update-function-code ...` (along with the necessary packaging steps). Or I have some Flask EB websites that I currently update with something like `eb deploy ...`. Both from my local CLI. Is there a way to wire things up so that `git push <CodeCommit repo> ...` performs these deployments, as it does with a CodeStar project built from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CodeCommit as a source provider in CodePipelines; if you deploy via CodePipelines, this should do what you need.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html#codecommit-create-pipeline

Let us know if this doesn't solve your problem.

-Paige@AWS

Comment: Has anything changed - can we add existing projects to CodeStar yet?

Comment: Doesn't appear so